# is this synchronization object implementation thread safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I have am reviewing a colleague's Visual Studio 2008 C++03 application application and I've come across an implementation of a thread synchronization primitive (below).

Assuming `SyncObject` is implemented correctly, is the use of a boolean in the below code to know if the resource is locked or unlocked thread-safe? If no, can you walk through a "ThreadA" does this and "ThreadB" does that situation so I understand your logic?

```
class CMyLock
{
public:
    CMyLock(SyncObject* object) 
        : object_(object), acquired_(false) 
    { 
    };

    // return true if the resource is locked within the given timeout period
    bool Lock(DWORD dwTimeOut = INFINITE)
    {
        acquired_ = object_->Lock(dwTimeOut);
        return acquired_;
    };

    // return true if the resource is unlocked
    bool Unlock()
    {
        if (acquired_)
            acquired_ = !object_->Unlock();
        return !acquired_;
    };

    // return true if the resource is locked
    bool IsLocked() { return acquired_; };

private:
    bool acquired_;
    // some thread synchronization primitive
    SyncObject* object_;
};
```

Comment: Doesn't use RAII = fail.

Comment: No, it can be stored in registries, cache and whatever else because of optimizations.

Comment: Can you walk me through the situation where it would fail?

Comment: Simple scenario: object is created in thread A then passed to thread B. Thread A will acquire the lock (m_bAcquired == true). Thread B tries to acquire the lock too but it sees m_bAcquired is false. Moreover someone can check m_bAcquired after m_pObject->Lock(dwTimeOut) but before its result is assigned to field. Same for Unlock. Assume nothing is atomic (even if it's not true) and you'll see many of this issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not threadsafe.

directly after `m_pObject->Unlock()` returns, another thread waiting on `m_pObject->Lock(dwTimeOut)` can return and set `m_bAcquired` to true, then the unlocking thread sets `m_bAcquired` to false and overwrites the locked state incorrectly (IsLocked will return false while the object is locked).

Answer (score 2):

I see several serious problems with this code.  In a code review, I would reject it.

1. It is not clear what this class is intended to be.  It might be a thin proxy to a primitive.  It might be an automatic locker.  In either case, the design is wrong,  and the documentation (none) does not elaborate.
2. It does not use RAII.  This is a good idea no matter what this object is intended to be, but in the case of an automatic locker it is especially important.
3. It retains it's own state, which could be out of sync with other instances in the same thread.  If, for example, you create 2 instances of this object on thread A, set one to `locked` and check the state of the other one, it should say `locked` but it won't.
4. Possibly most importantly, it is re-inventing the wheel at best.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **no**

You need to lock for reading too, or you risk seeing a stale state.

Answer (score 1):

no it's not - at least from what I can see. What may happen is that one thread calls lock and gets the lock and another thread accesses m_bAcquired before it's updated by the thread the causes the lock.

That's why you need a lock for reading as well asl Matthieu M. stated.

A: Lock
after m_pObject is locked but before m_bAcquired is set
B: IsLocked
--> returns false
A - still in Lock: m_pObject = true

so B has false information.

Other problem:
Unlock relies on m_bAcquired.

I think this object is meant to be used from within one single thread. So each thread has its own CSingleLock instance but they all use the same SyncObject. In this case, only SyncObject needs to be thread safe and it works.